# Ionic - Send Component as Parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have an ionic application with many pages and I have a filter button for each page that opens a filter popover with categories check-boxes. When you click click on a checkbox I want to refresh the background component without closing the popover. I am trying to do something like this but getting `this.Page.Refresh() is not a function`

**SalesPage.ts**

```
export class SalesPage {    
        OpenFilterCat()  // WHEN YOU CLICK THE FILTER BUTTON  
            let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(CategoryPopover,
                                {
                                    Page: this
                                });
                            popover.present({
                                ev: event
                            });

            }
        Refresh()
        {
           //REFRESH COMPONENT SERVER SIDE HTTP CALL
        }

        }
```

**CustomersPage.ts**

```
export class CustomersPage{    
    OpenFilterCat()    
        let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(CategoryPopover,
                            {
                                Page: this
                            });
                        popover.present({
                            ev: event

              });  
    }
    Refresh()
    {
       //REFRESH COMPONENT SERVER SIDE HTTP CALL
    }
}
```

**Category.ts**

```
export class CategoryPopover {
    Page: any;

    constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController
        , public modalCtrl: ModalController
        , public navParams: NavParams
        , public events: Events) {

        this.Page = this.navParams.get('Page');

}
     RefreshBackground() // AFTER CHANGING SOME CHECKBOXES REFRESH THE BACKGROUND
       {
          this.Page.Refresh();
       }
}
```

Comment: you dont refresh/reload a page in angular.. you set the relevant data again and let the binding do the change

Comment: I am doing server side calls